# Is there a way to save a fixed pytorch tensor in a pytorch nn module as a parameter?

Tags: python, pytorch

So I have a fixed tensor, which are centroids that I pre-calculated. Essentially the centroids matrix is N classes by D dimensions. I want to save this in a Pytorch module at the end of training in such a way that when I save this model and load it this parameter will be there for me to use after loading the saved checkpoint. Also there should never be a gradient passing through this matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably register it as a [buffer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer). Buffers will not be updated with gradient descent, but will be saved alongside the model. It's typically used for the mean and variance of the `batchnorm` layers, which are not learnt with backprop.

That would be like :

```
# replace this with your actual model
my_model = nn.Linear(10,10)
# Replace this tensor with your actual centroids
centroid_tensor = torch.randn(2,2)
# Keep this to register the centroids as a buffer
my_model.register_buffer(name="centroids", tensor=centroids_tensor)
# if you want to access your buffers:
for buf in my_model.named_buffers():
    print(buf)
```

As explained in the documentation link above, the registered buffer will be persistent by default, which means it will be included in the [state dict](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict) of the module ; thus it will be saved and loaded alongside the model.

Comment: how do I do this?